# multi filter mapping React Js

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs, filter, mapping

i am writing a search of objects with multiple filters. The two filters perform the following checks

1)is someone assigned to the case (caseWorkers)
2)is this type of document present (resoStatus)

I have written out the front part of the filter which functions like so:

if a user clicks on a name to search for caseWorkers ("firstName lastName")it feeds through and ends up a string of that name in an array called filters on the page where the search is rendered

if a user clicks on the documents it pushes to the same string array "hasRepresentation" "hasTaxForms".

The model that is being searched (prospect) looks something like:

```
{
fullName: '',
resoStatus:{
representation:[],
federalReso:[],
},
caseWorkers:{
originators:[],
taxPreparers:[]
}
}
```

so there is an array of objects that looks like that and an array of strings called filters with names or true false evaluations.

```
filters = ["Mickey Gray", "hasRepresentation"]
```

so i need to map over the filters look for certain aspects of the string /has/ or ' ' and and then map over prospects filtering by the sub arrays in caseWorkers and resoStatus.

I have a very clear understanding of what i want but i cant figure out how to layer all of the different arrays that need to be considered.  Here is the lastest version of the react code.

```
  {(filters.length > 0 && prospects.length > 0 && prospect.caseWorkers) ||
        (filters.length > 0 && prospects.length > 0 && prospect.resoStatus)
          ? prospects.filter(
              (prospects, filters, i) =>
                prospects[i].caseWorkers.originators.name ===
                filters
                  .map((filter) => filter.includes(" "))
                  .map((filtered) => (
                    <ProspectItem
                      key={filtered._id}
                      filtered={filtered}
                      prosp={prosp}
                    />
                  ))
            )
          : prospects.map((prospect) => (
              <ProspectItem
                key={prospect._id}
                prospect={prospect}
                prosp={prosp}
              />
            ))}
```

this is another method i've considered mapping filters to find a part of prospects.

```
        {(filters.length > 0 && prospects.length > 0 && prospect.caseWorkers) ||
        (filters.length > 0 && prospects.length > 0 && prospect.resoStatus)
          ? filters.map((filter) =>
              prospects
                .find((prospect) => prospect.caseWorkers.name === filter)
                .map((filtered) => (
                  <ProspectItem
                    key={filtered._id}
                    filtered={filtered}
                    prosp={prosp}
                  />
                ))
            )
          : prospects.map((prospect) => (
              <ProspectItem
                key={prospect._id}
                prospect={prospect}
                prosp={prosp}
              />
            ))}
```

how do i stack multiple filters and evaluate multiple sections of the same object for values for a map.

Answer (score 0):

So I don't follow the question completely, but I think an important thing to realize is that within react you can use normal javascript variables too.
You don't have to formulate everything as an expression, statements can be used as well.

E.G.

```js
const MyComponent = ({items, filters})=>{
    const processedFilters = processFilters(filters); // returns filter functions for instance
    const filteredItems = filters.reduce((items, filter)=>filter(items), items);
    return <div>
        {filteredItems.map(item=><div>{item.something}</div>)}
    </div>;
}
```

in this case processFilters could look something like this:

```js
function processFilters(filters){
    return filters.map(filter=>{
        if(filter.match(/^has/)) 
            return item=>item[filter];
        else if(filterMatchesSomeCondition(filter)) 
            return item=>checksSomethingElse(filter, item);
    })
}
```

This notation might not be the most intuitive way of doing things, so this code achieves roughly the same and may be easier to follow:

```js
const MyComponent = ({items, filters})=>{
    for(let filter of filters){
        if(filter.match(/^has/)) 
            items = items.filter(item=>item[filter]==true);
        else if(filterMatchesSomeCondition(filter)) 
            items = items.filter(item=>checksSomethingElse(filter, item));
    }
    return <div>
        {items.map(item=><div>{item.something}</div>)}
    </div>;
}
```

I hope this information is of any use.
If not, I am happy to help if you can formulate the problem a little more abstractly.

Also I am unsure whether formatting the filters as strings is the best idea, since it's rather ambiguous. Something simple as an object array like this:

```
[{type: "hasName", value: "John"}, {type:"hasMaxSomething", value:3}]
```

would already help making the filters purposes easier to understand. It may also prevent bugs since you will be able to pass more data for the filter without having to encode things in strange ways.

Comment: so for every filter evaluate what it looks like then use that to point towards a specific section of the mapped array to filter the elements based on different sections

Comment: f = [1,2,3]
p = [name:' ', worker:{[salesPerson:{name:'1'}], caseStatus:{thisSet:[2]}]

iterate through f and check in worker or case status for values like f and remove those that arent.

Comment: I am still not entirely sure about what you mean, since the syntax you provided: `{[...], ...}` isn't valid javascript. But in general to me it seems like you can just apply filters sequentially. Maybe my example wasn't clear enough, I've written it a bit simpler now.